# how to save multiple dropdownlist yii2

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii2

I'm trying to save multiple data from a dropdownlist, I have 2 tables Asistencia and Mecanico in the table Asistencia i have this in the _form

```
<?php
echo $form->field($model, 'mecanico_id[]')            
 ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Mecanico::find()->all(), 'id_mecanico', 'nombre'),
 [
  'multiple'=>'multiple',
  'class'=>'chosen-select input-md required',              
 ]             
)->label("Mecanicos"); 
?>
```

i know if i want to save multiple data i have to change in controllers-> actionCreate/Update but i dont know how. Here is my actionCreate

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Asistencia();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_asistencia]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

I need sample controller code explaining how to save multiple items from a drop down list to the database, as well as update the list of saved items. Thanks.

here is my table of Asistencia
[Asistencia table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lcz8w.png)

Table of Mecanico
[Mecanico table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IskhZ.png)

and the relation of those 2 table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GKaj.png)

Comment: Is `mecanico_id[]` is saved as multiple record or as a single record. No of items selected in dropdownlist equals to new no of records or  you have single field to save multiple dropdown options

Comment: mecanico_id is a FK of Asistencia Table, FOREIGN KEY (mecanico_id) REFERENCES Mecanico(id_mecanico)

Comment: can you show the models or the schema for the tables involved it would be much easier as what look like you are using the default traditional save method.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam okay i edit my post and added the tables that im using

Comment: For each selected `mecanico_id`, you want to save record in `Asistencia`? Selection is 4 then new records will be 4?

Comment: @InsaneSkull i want to save all mecanico_id in one record in Asistencia

Answer (score 0):

For example you have Product and Category many to many relation.

In your Product model,

1. Declare field:

   public $categories_ids;
2. Put it in 'safe' in rules():

   [['categories_ids'], 'safe']

3.Declare AfterSave function:

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes) {
        // If this is not a new record, unlink all records related through relationship 'categories'
        if(!$this->isNewRecord) {
            // We unlink all related records from the 'categories' relationship.
            $this->unlinkAll('categories', true);
            // NOTE: because this is a many to many relationship, we send 'true' as second parameter
            // so the records in the pivot table are deleted. However on a one to many relationship
            // if we send true, this method will delete the records on the related table. Because of this,
            // send false on one to many relationships if you don't want the related records deleted.
        }

        foreach($this->categories_ids as $category_id) {
            // Find and link every model from the array of ids we got from the user.
            $category = Category::findOne($category_id);
            $this->link('categories', $category);
        }

        parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    }
```

4. Decare AfterFind function():

   public function afterFind(){
   parent::afterFind();
   $this->categories_ids = ArrayHelper::getColumn($this->categories, 'id');
   }
5. Declare relation:

   public function getCategories() {
   return $this->hasMany(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category_id'])->viaTable('product_category', ['product_id' => 'id']);
   }

I hope it will help to you.